# Non-root users cannot access NFS mounted directory

Tags: debian, nfs

I have a Synology NAS sharing a "MEDIA" folder by NFS.

[image: screenshot]

I would like to access this folder from my Plex Media Server (running on Debian).

I added this line to the /etc/fstab file:

```
nas.lan:/volume2/MEDIA /plexlibrary nfs user,auto 0 0
```

And I can successfully mount it and access it with the root account.

```
root@plex:~# mount /plexlibrary/
root@plex:~# ls -lh /plexlibrary/
total 16K
drwxrwxrwx 3 1026 users 4.0K Jul  8 21:54 Documentaire
drwxrwxrwx 2 root users 4.0K Jul  6 14:31 @eaDir
drwxrwxrwx 3 1026 users 4.0K Jul  8 21:54 Films
drwxrwxrwx 8 root users 4.0K Jul  8 21:38 Series
```

The problem is that the Plex Media Server runs with the **plex** account privileges and this account cannot access the mounted directory.

```
root@plex:~# su plex
plex@plex:/root$ ls -lh /plexlibrary/
ls: cannot open directory /plexlibrary/: Permission denied
```

What did I forget?

Comment: Note that home setting questions are off-topic here. Your question should have a better home either at [SU] or at [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: All right I posted it on Super User. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: I know this was quite awhile ago but I wonder if you sorted this. I am facing the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

You Must Mount your file system nfs befor start init in linux you must config partion in /etc/fstab

and don't forget found default mount directory of your software and mount your nfs

See Example :
http://xmodulo.com/2012/04/how-to-mount-nfs-share-as-regular-user.html

Comment: The plex user is already able to mount the network share because of the entry in /etc/fstab but he doesn't have read/write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I use Plex Media Server installed on an Intel NUC running Ubuntu ... these are my fstab entries to mount a share on a QNAP NAS:

```
//10.0.10.222/Media/ /media/droid-NAS-mount/Media  cifs guest,rw,auto,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//10.0.10.222/BACKUPS/ /media/droid-NAS-mount/Backups  cifs guest,rw,auto,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

If you're going to go the cifs route, make sure the `cifs-utils` package is installed..
but be aware that my setup allows all guests write access, so it may not be what you're after in a more 'public' or shared network

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Windows share and I do not want all guest in the network to have write permission :s

Comment: Are you able to add a corresponding user on the NAS with the same UID as your plex user? You can then make sure that the user has permissions on the NAS, and when the partition is mounted, that user should be able to read from the share.

Comment: No. The GUI does not allow changing the UID of created users...

Answer (score 0):

I had directory permissions set too narrowly on the host, I `chmod 755 <dir>` to fix it.

In your case, the original `sudo ls` should have worked, but it's possible that you have root squashed (requests made by `root` on the client are squashed to `nobody` on the host).